# How I can use OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) with cte insert into temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, common-table-expression, recursive-query

When I call this with these parameters(`@MediaSellerID = 138, @StartDate = N'9/1/2020', @EndDate = N'10/7/2020'`) it returns data successfully.

But when I passed these parameters(`@MediaSellerID = 213,@StartDate = '8/4/2020',@EndDate = N'11/25/2020'`)
this error occurs.

Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetAvailableDatesforCampaign, Line 81 [Batch Start Line 2]
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

If anyone has this solution (`OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)`) then please also mention this statement place. thanks

```
  ALTER Procedure [dbo].[GetAvailableDatesforCampaign]  
  -- exec GetAvailableDatesforCampaign 2,getdate(),getdate()
    @MediaSellerID int,
    @StartDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime   

AS 
BEGIN

SET FMTONLY OFF

Declare @Frequency as varchar(200)
Declare @Weeks as varchar(200)
Declare @Days as varchar(200)
Declare @CopyDeadlineDays as int
Declare @DayItem as varchar(20)
Declare @WeekItem as varchar(200)
Declare @DayNumber as int

Delete from tblCampaignDates


select 
     @Frequency=MediaFrequency,
     @Weeks=BroadcastDays,
     @Days=BroadcastDaysWeeks,
     @CopyDeadlineDays=Copydeadline
from 
     tblMediaSeller where MediaSeller_ID=@MediaSellerID

    

CREATE TABLE 
   #TempAvailableDates
   ( 
   AvailableDate datetime default GetDate()
   )



CREATE TABLE 
   #TempAllDates
   ( 
     AllDate datetime,   
     DayNames varchar(20),
     Weeknumber int
    )



IF(@Frequency='Bi-Weekly' or @Frequency='Weekly' or @Frequency='Monthly')
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE MY_CURSOR2 CURSOR 
    LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
    FOR 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
     Item 
    FROM 
    dbo.SplitString(@Days)
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
    OPEN MY_CURSOR2
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR2 INTO @DayItem
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
           BEGIN    
        -- Select All dates of those days in tblMediaSeller (Adv Publishing day) from start date to End dates   
              Set @DayNumber= CASE WHEN @DayItem='Monday' THEN 1
              
                                WHEN @DayItem='Tuesday' THEN 2
                                WHEN @DayItem='Wednesday' THEN 3
                                WHEN @DayItem='Thursday' THEN 4
                                WHEN @DayItem='Friday' THEN 5
                                WHEN @DayItem='Saturday' THEN 6
                                WHEN @DayItem='Sunday' THEN 7
                                ELSE 0 END
            
            IF(@DayNumber<>0)
            BEGIN
               SET DATEFIRST @DayNumber; -- First day of the week is set to monday                    
                 WITH CTE(dt) 
                 AS
                 (
                       SELECT @StartDate     
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, dt)
                        FROM CTE
                       WHERE dt <@EndDate 
                  ) 
                 
               INSERT INTO 
                  #TempAllDates
                      SELECT 
                      CONVERT(date,dt), 
                      datename(dw, dt), 
                      DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, dt), 0), dt)                       
                   FROM 
                      CTE  
                   WHERE 
                      datepart ("dw", dt) = 1;
                      
                      
             END     
            FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR2 INTO @DayItem
            END
            CLOSE MY_CURSOR2
     DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR2
    

 Set @WeekItem= REPLACE(@Weeks, 'Week', '');

           DECLARE @ActualStartDate as Datetime
           Set @ActualStartDate = (Select top 1 AllDate from #TempAllDates)

        IF(@CopyDeadlineDays is null)
        BEGIN
            IF(@ActualStartDate>= DATEADD(day,5,getdate()))
            BEGIN
                Insert into
                   #TempAvailableDates
                Select
                   AllDate
                From 
                   #TempAllDates
                   
                WHERE
                   Weeknumber in (select cast(item as int) from dbo.SplitString(@WeekItem)) 
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                Insert into
                   #TempAvailableDates
                Select
                   AllDate
                From 
                   #TempAllDates
                WHERE
                   Weeknumber in (select cast(item as int) from dbo.SplitString(@WeekItem)) 
                   AND AllDate>=DATEADD(day,5,getdate())    
            END 
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
             IF(@ActualStartDate>= DATEADD(day,@CopyDeadlineDays,getdate()))
            BEGIN
                Insert into
                   #TempAvailableDates
                Select
                   AllDate
                From 
                   #TempAllDates
                WHERE
                   Weeknumber in (select cast(item as int) from dbo.SplitString(@WeekItem))          
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                Insert into
                   #TempAvailableDates
                Select
                   AllDate
                From 
                   #TempAllDates
                WHERE
                   Weeknumber in (select cast(item as int) from dbo.SplitString(@WeekItem)) 
                   AND AllDate>=DATEADD(day,@CopyDeadlineDays,getdate())    
            END 
        END
       
END

ELSE
BEGIN
    IF(@CopyDeadlineDays is null)
    begin
       IF(@StartDate>= DATEADD(day,5,getdate()))
       BEGIN
           Insert into
               #TempAvailableDates
           SELECT  TOP 
               (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
                Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @StartDate) 
           FROM 
                sys.all_objects a
           CROSS JOIN 
                sys.all_objects b;  
                
       END 
       ELSE
       BEGIN
           SET @StartDate=@StartDate+5
           Insert into
               #TempAvailableDates
           SELECT  TOP 
               (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
                Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @StartDate) 
           FROM 
                sys.all_objects a
           CROSS JOIN 
                sys.all_objects b;
       END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF(@StartDate>= DATEADD(day,@CopyDeadlineDays,getdate()))
       BEGIN
           Insert into
                #TempAvailableDates
           SELECT  TOP 
                (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
                 Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @StartDate) 
           FROM 
                 sys.all_objects a
           CROSS JOIN 
                 sys.all_objects b;     
       END 
       ELSE
       BEGIN
           SET @StartDate=@StartDate+@CopyDeadlineDays
           Insert into
                #TempAvailableDates
           SELECT  TOP 
               (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
                Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @StartDate) 
           FROM 
                sys.all_objects a
           CROSS JOIN 
                sys.all_objects b;
       END  
    END
END

Insert into
   tblCampaignDates
Select 
   AvailableDate 
from #TempAvailableDates
Select AvailableDate from tblCampaignDates
END
```

Comment: Put the `OPTION` at the end of the query, after the `WHERE`.

Comment: when I put at end error occurs

Comment: Update your question with how you added the option, include the error you get in your question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
 WITH CTE(dt) AS (
               SELECT @StartDate     
               UNION ALL
               SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, dt)
                FROM CTE
               WHERE dt <@EndDate 
          ) 
       INSERT INTO #TempAllDates
           SELECT CONVERT(date,dt), datename(dw, dt), DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, dt), 0), dt)                       
           FROM CTE  
           WHERE datepart(dw, dt) = 1
           OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bbcd5f10693d5668c4ba0ed28085b99f) is a db<>fiddle with a much simpler example.